# How do I add infinite-scroll to mean.js modules?

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am trying to add infinite-scroll to the demo Articles modules that comes out of the box with mean.js.

I installed infinite-scroll using `ng install infinite-scroll` and I can see the module is available.

In the `list-articles.client.view.html` page I added the directives to the div list-group.

```
<div class="list-group" infinite-scroll="myPagingFunction()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
```

I created the `myPagingFunction` so that is just calls `find()` and I limited find to 50 results.  I figured I'd worry about the real implementation of that function later.

However, I can't figure out how to get mean.js to recognize the directive.  I tried adding infinite-scroll to the `config.js` list of dependencies. But then I just get blank pages on the site.

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','infinite-scroll'];
```

Comment: Please either inline your code related to the problem or link a jsfiddle/codepen demo reproducing the problem.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.  The site fails to render if I try to add the 'infinite-scroll' to the publis/config.js file.


var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','infinite-scroll'];

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this.  I found the ng-scroll was already part of angular.

In the client view I made these changes:

```
<div class="list-group" ng-scroll-viewport style="height: 70vh;">
    <a  ng-animate="'animate'" ng-scroll="article in datasource"  class="list-group-item" >
```

In the control I added the datasource get method.  In here I needed to deal with scrolling past the top.  Not sure if this is 100% correct, but it seems to work.  I also had to convert the json result set into an array of objects so that the ng-scroll works correctly.

```
$scope.datasource = {
        get: function(index, count, success) {

           if (index>-10) {
            if (index < 1) index = 1;

              var arts = Arts.query({index: index, count: count, filter: $scope.q});
              var results = [];

              articles.$promise.then(function (data) {

                   for (var key in data) {
                       if (data[key].name) {
                        results .push(data[key]);
                       }
                   }
                   success(results);
              });

            } else {
                success([]);
            }

      }
     };
```

I then modified the query in my server side controller to do an .skip(req.query.index).limit(req.query.count).  This limits the result set to the rows that need to fill the viewport.